# What does the followin dashed and filled arrow mean in this Java UML diagram?

Tags: java, interface, uml

What does the dashed and filled arrow mean in the following UML diagram for java interfaces?

[image: uml diagram]

Comment: Voting to move to programmers SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dashed and filled - usually in UML - is synonym of some kind of dependency. `IInterval<E>` should depend on `Successorable<E>`, for example it's used as the return type of a method.

Check this handy UML guide: http://www.holub.com/goodies/uml/

Comment: Between interfaces that's the only possible dependency, right? Because they only have method signatures?

Comment: They could define also constants, but that's an antipattern (see Bloch - Effective Java 2nd edition - item 19) and this shouldn't be used.

Answer (score 2):

The dashed arrow represents a dependency relationship. From [Dependency relationships](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cdepend.html)

> In UML modeling, a dependency relationship is a relationship in which
>   changes to one model element (the supplier) impact another model
>   element (the client). You can use dependency relationships in class
>   diagrams, component diagrams, deployment diagrams, and use case
>   diagrams.
>
> You can also use a dependency relationship to represent precedence,
>   where one model element must precede another.
>
> Dependency relationships usually do not have names.

While, the solid arrow represents a generalization relationship. From [Generalization relationships](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/rtnlhelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xtools.modeler.doc/topics/cdepend.html)

> In UML modeling, a generalization relationship is a relationship in
>   which one model element (the child) is based on another model element
>   (the parent). Generalization relationships are used in class,
>   component, deployment, and use case diagrams.
>
> To comply with UML semantics, the model elements in a generalization
>   relationship must be the same type. For example, a generalization
>   relationship can be used between actors or between use cases; however,
>   it cannot be used between an actor and a use case.
>
> You can add generalization relationships to capture attributes,
>   operations, and relationships in a parent model element and then reuse
>   them in one or more child model elements. Because the child model
>   elements in generalizations inherit the attributes, operations, and
>   relationships of the parent, you must only define for the child the
>   attributes, operations, or relationships that are distinct from the
>   parent.
>
> The parent model element can have one or more children, and any child
>   model element can have one or more parents. It is more common to have
>   a single parent model element and multiple child model elements.